# Как выровнять на flex по линии?

Tags: css, html5, вёрстка, flexbox

Есть такая конструкция:

```
<div class="row no-gutters">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
        <p class="text-center text-uppercase">Заявка по телефону или через сайт</p>    
        <div class="adv-stage-one">
            <img src="assets/img/stage-one.png" alt="Заявка по телефону или через сайт" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
        <div class="adv-stage-two">
              <img src="assets/img/stage-two.png" alt="Выезд на объект" />
        </div>   
        <p class="text-center text-uppercase">Выезд на объект</p> 
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
        <p class="text-center text-uppercase">Заключение договора на разработку и реализацию проекта</p>    
        <div class="adv-stage-three">
            <img src="assets/img/stage-three.png" alt="Заключение договора на разработку и реализацию проекта" />
        </div>                
    </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/denism300/jk6feLrt/1/
картинки одинакового размера, количество строк текста разное.
если к классу .row добавить класс .align-items-baseline, то все выровняется по базису, но относительно текста. 
А как выровнять по базису относительно всего?
т.е. мне нужно, чтобы и картинки и текст были прижаты к условной горизонтальной линии.

Comment: align-item-center очевидно

Comment: Если я правильно понял, попробуй добавить для блоков с классом `col-*` вот эти классы `d-flex flex-column justify-content-between`

Comment: не совсем. результат должен быть таким, как на картинке. все должно быть прижато к красной линии https://c.radikal.ru/c19/1902/f9/f6a3eb92e984.png

Comment: Именно так как на картинке можно сделать задав отрицательные марджины, равные высоте картинки. Одними флексами боюсь не обойтись

Comment: @denism300 Такого вида можно добиться задав фиксированную высоту блокам, а там уже прижимать содержимое к верху или низу, либо размещать контент не колонками, а по строкам и ровнять содержимое строк по вертикали.